# How to get content tree back from expanded content area view

Tags: sitecore-client

I'm a content author using Sitecore 9 (maybe 9.1?) and when I went to preview a page in the content editor area I expanded the content editor, which hid the content tree. I am unable to get the content tree back and I do have the content tree selected in View and within the view tab in application options. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just move your mouse to the left side of the screen until you see a small arrow there (it may look a bit different in other browsers).

[image]

Then click and drag to the right.

Comment: I have also tried that, it doesn't move.

Comment: It does. Just make sure you place your mouse at the "height" of content tree, not at the height of the tabs bar. See on my screenshot - it's at the level of item name ("Home"). If you try at the level of the "Content" tab, it won't work.

Comment: You may also try another browser and expand content tree there then switch back to the original browser and log out and log in again.

Comment: Thank you Marek, you were right about the specific height of where to drag. It worked!

Comment: @Shannon I'm glad it worked. If you find this answer useful, you should mark it as correct. Upvoting is also encouraged